# c# draw function error

Tags: c#, image, winforms, button, draw

So I made this function that draws a "button" with a picturebox and image as parameters. The button is supposed to be blue when active and grey when inactive but somehow the fuction draws a blue line over the button when it is supposed to be inactive

[image: button resources]

[image: grey background with blue line]

How do I remove that blue line?

```
void DrawButton(PictureBox PIC, Image IMG)
    {
        using (Font myFont = new Font("Century Gothic", 11))
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(IMG, PIC.Width, PIC.Height);
            bitmap.MakeTransparent();
            Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
            // PIC.Tag is "Next"
            graph.DrawString(PIC.Tag.ToString(), myFont, Brushes.White, new Point(42, 0));
            PIC.Image = bitmap;
            graph.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

And the calls of my function:

```
    private void picNext_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_CURRENT_PAGE * 12 < DB.GetOnlinePlayers())
            DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_no_hover);
        else DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_no_active);
    }
    private void picNext_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_CURRENT_PAGE * 12 < DB.GetOnlinePlayers())
            DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_hover);
        else DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_no_active);
    }

    private void picNext_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_CURRENT_PAGE * 12 < DB.GetOnlinePlayers())
            DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_take);
        else DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_no_active);
    }

    private void picNext_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_CURRENT_PAGE * 12 < DB.GetOnlinePlayers())
            DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_hover);
        else DrawButton(picNext, Properties.Resources.play_no_active);
    }
```

Comment: Is this all the code there is? If yes, how do your `Properties.Resources.play_*` resources look like?

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: @DirkVollmar I added an image.

Comment: @TaW I'm using Winforms

Comment: Is the Pbox's BackgroundColor blue? Don't use [MakeTransparent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzst10b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)! You probably only made one line with the the default color (LightGray)  transparent.. Use graph.Clear(Color.Transparent) to create an empty bitmap!

Comment: Several suggestions: 1) prepare the bitmaps in advance, as this is horribly inefficient. 2) use `using` when instantiating the `Graphics`, 3) your previous `PIC.Image` doesn't get disposed, so you might to do this manually. Also, to help you debug, you can use `Bitmap.Save` withing the `DrawButton` method to save the image to disk (with a timestamp, for example) and identify where this line gets drawn.

Comment: @Taw is right, if you remove `MakeTransparent`, the problem will likely go away. If only removes `LightGray` by default. Also, your images are Pngs, meaning they have a transparent alpha channel, so it's likely you don't need this call at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems related to the transparency. Apparently the blue line comes from the previously active version of the button shining through. Here is my guess what is going on:

You are calling the [`bitmap.MakeTransparent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zzst10b(v=vs.110).aspx) method, which *“makes the default transparent color transparent for this Bitmap. If no transparent color is specified by the system, `LightGray` is the transparent color.*”

Your inactive button bitmap probably uses `LightGray` (`#FFD3D3D3`) for the pixels that now appear blue because they are made transparent.

The fix is to use another color for the pixels that need to be transparent  and then call `bitmap.MakeTransparent` and pass that color into the method, e.g.:

```
// Get the color of a background pixel.
Color backColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(1, 1);

// Make backColor transparent for myBitmap.
myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColor);
```

Comment: Since these images are Pngs, they probably already have alpha transparency and there is no need to use `MakeTransparent` at all.